# Directadmin server performance lower than ispconfig?

Tags: performance, server, directadmin

I am running a web-application on 2 servers, but get strange performance problem.

server 1:
Core i5-4770 3.40GHz with 8gig DDR3 running  ISPConfig server with PHP/Mysql.

server 2:
Core i7-5930K 3.50GHz  with 64gig DDR4 running directadmin with PHP/Mysql

the new server (2) is more powerful, but it get slower page results than the old server.

any suggestions how to find the problem?

Comment: Without any configuration and server location details there couldn't be any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not getting this issues due to Directadmin server. You will have to optimize your Apache and MySQL for the better performance. I will suggest you please enable some php cache modules on your server.

Answer (score -1):

What version of PHP do you use and how it's connected to apache:
PHP:FPM
MOD-PHP
etc...
You probably whould like to use PHP:FPM from the security and performance reasons.

One more suggestion. Default my.cnf config file has no additional configuration on DA. So MySQL performance could be really bad because of that. Please add you my.cnf file here and share info how much RAM do you have. With that I could try to pump your config.